# Angularjs - `ng-model` in multi-dimension array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

I have this `object`:

```
[{
  'name': '2015',
  'section': '001',
  'subsections': [{
    subsection:'aa',
    mainelements: ['cc','dd']
    },{
    subsection:'bb',
    mainelements: ['ee','ff']
    }]
}]
```

and I can display them in `html`

```
  <body>
    <button ng-click="new()">New</button>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="audit in audits">
          <span ng-hide="editing"><h5>{{audit.name}}</h5></span></br>
          <input ng-show="editing" type="text" ng-model="audit.name"  size="30" placeholder="add name here"></br>
          <span ng-hide="editing">{{audit.section}}</span></br>
          <input ng-show="editing" type="text" ng-model="audit.section"  size="30" placeholder="add section here"></br>
          <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="subsection in audit.subsections">
                  <span ng-hide="editing">{{subsection.subsection}}</span></br>
                  <input ng-show="editing" type="text" ng-model="subsection.subsection"  size="30" placeholder="add subsection here"></br>
                  <ul>
                        <li ng-repeat="mainelement in subsection.mainelements">
                          <span ng-hide="editing">{{mainelement}}</span></br>
                            <input ng-show="editing" type="text" ng-model="mainelement"  size="30" placeholder="add mainelement here"></br>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
          <div id="buttons">
            <button type="button" ng-hide="editing" ng-click="editing = true">Edit</button>
            <button type="button" ng-show="editing" ng-click="editing = false">Save</button>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </body>
```

But the problem is, I need all `ng-model` to be dynamic so that I can edit them separately. In this case, only `audit.name` and `audit.section` is dynamic. But `subsection.subsection` and `main element` are not.

When I do this:

```
$scope.logging = function(i) {
        var editaudit = $scope.audits[i];
        console.log(editaudit.name);
        console.log(editaudit.section);
        console.log(editaudit.subsections);
        console.log(editaudit.subsections.mainelements);
    }
```

and get this

```
[Log] 2015
[Log] market map
[Log] [{subsection: "aa", mainelements: ["cc", "dd"], $$hashKey: "object:9"}, {subsection: "bb", mainelements: ["ee", "ff"], $$hashKey: "object:10"}]
[Log] undefined
```

1. I can I get all `ng-model` to be dynamic?
2. How to access to `mainelement` which is an object in `Key-value` form?

Update:

I managed to get all my elements to show up:

```
<!--Html -->
<ul>
              <li class="bitcard" ng-repeat="subsection in audit.subsections">
                  <span ng-hide="editing">{{audit.subsections[$index].subsection}}</span></br>
                  <input ng-show="editing" type="text" ng-model="audit.subsections[$index].subsection"  size="30" placeholder="add subsection here"></br>
                  <ul>
                        <li class="bitcard" ng-repeat="mainelements in audit.subsections[$index].mainelements">
                          <span ng-hide="editing">{{mainelements}}</span></br>
                            <input ng-show="editing" type="text" ng-model="mainelements"  size="30" placeholder="add mainelement here"></br>
                        </li>
                  </ul>
              </li>
          </ul>
```

But now the issue is `ng-model="mainelements"` at the 5th last line is not unique. Is there a way to have second index like `$index02` or other alternative ways to do this?

Comment: can u provide a plunker as everything seems fine to me...

Comment: I don't get it when you say all to be dynamic. please be more specific. about accessing mainelement, you could use ng-model="mainelement[0]" and ng-model="mainelement[1]" if want to access each of the members.

Comment: Also note that using that much of ngShow and ngHide directives alongside 3ngRepeats is seriously breaking the angular app performance.

Comment: [plunker here](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFj7n7SI2e43WF4btVxd?p=info)

Comment: @FarzadYZ Please take a look at the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFj7n7SI2e43WF4btVxd?p=info) and click on `edit `. It will be nice if you can suggest something more optimum.

Comment: I don't really understand what this code is trying to accomplish, but I'm not seeing anything unusual in the `edit` button in the plunker you just posted in comments.  However, the `duplicate` function doesn't exactly make sense, because you seem to be trying to duplicate a selected line, but you have no way of selecting a line, and the button is outside the `ng-repeat` which means it doesn't have access to an `$index` value that you are trying to pass.

Comment: @Claies At the moment, `duplicate` serve as `console.log` to test if I am getting back the same items. I will edit it. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2):

So you have an array of subsections and within that another array of mainelements.

As such you need to access each item with a valid index.
Hence your `console.log(editaudit.subsections.mainelements);` logs out `undefined`. Change it to `console.log(editaudit.subsections[index].mainelements);`

And in your view you can also access array items by index within the `ng-repeat`.
Simply use `audit.subsections[$index].subsection` instead of `subsection.subsection` and `mainelements[$index]` instead of `mainelement` to bind to your model. 
Not sure what your mean by "get all `ng-model` to by dynamic" but I hope this gets you going.

Comment: You can still use `mainelements[$index]` as $index always refers to the current loop you are in. Read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat). And please accept this answer if it is correct (to help others)